# Regular service intervals

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, equipment, maintenance

I am an owner of a dual boiler E61 machine (lelit bianca) for 3 years and I often hear that one should get them to professional maintenance/service all 2-3 years for descaling (not backflush) and to replace rubber o-rings, tube, what not and the manufacturer expects you to do it. However my manual only has one statement, that when I descale I shall use „natural“ stuff. (Not very helpful IMHO). It seems to me when I just replace the shower head basket and o-ring when it feels right and descale it in 1-2 years it should be fine. (1-2 x2 shoots + steam / d, 1kg coffee beans / month, 10°dh, 1,786mmol/l, using the resin filters in the tank)

Do you have some, at best authoritative, opinion about this service advice? What descaler is recommended?